# Universal image loader Resizes and change language of images when I didn't asked for that apparently

Tags: android, image

I'm using this library to load images.
My images usually work as buttons, when I click them it changes, so there I use `ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage...`
The problem is the image just resizes to get smaller and that happens infinitely.
Also, it loads the images of drawable-es folder so it shows the images in spanish so localization it's not working fine with this either.
Here is my layout:
https://i.gyazo.com/4c38b4cc92cc9122d6d22688b6231870.png
This is what happens when I click the "super easy" button
https://i.gyazo.com/2d63573e4b2f7b15bd395a28b18ffbe5.png
As you can see, the size and language changes, the same happens to all my menus.

this is my DisplayImageOptions:

```
defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true).imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
            .build();
```

this is how I generally load images:

```
modo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mode2);
if (modo3 == 0) {
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(
                "drawable://" + R.drawable.classic, modo, defaultOptions);
        modo2 = "classic";
    } else if (modo3 == 1) {
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(
                "drawable://" + R.drawable.trial, modo, defaultOptions);
        modo2 = "trial";
    } else if (modo3 == 2) {
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(
                "drawable://" + R.drawable.challenge, modo, defaultOptions);
        modo2 = "challenge";
    }
```

I don't want to resize images when clicked and it's obvious I don't want spanish images to show to an english user.
How can I solve both problems?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try: http://square.github.io/picasso/ ? Works better.

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla I tried it first but I don't like that fading before showing images that actually make them gone and modifies the entire layout to fill the space that image used to use, I know that happens in a matter of milliseconds but I would not show that to potential users and it happens even if I prefetch all the images needed

Comment: well... that's a setting you can remove like this: .noFade()

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla same, noFade() doesn't solve that problem with the image gone some milliseconds while loading.
omg, tried 3 libraries (picasso, glide, universal...) and none of them works as intended